# How to convert curl command in shell script to python using requests library

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to pull data from github api using specific search query and put it into a .txt file. I am able to do so by through curl and shell but I need to do it in python which I am very unfamiliar with. I have seen the requests library

I've tried using this website https://curl.trillworks.com/ and using requests library but I can't seem to wrap my head around how to format the request.

```
curl  -H "Authorization: token xxx" 'https://api.github.com' "https://github.com/api/v3/search/repositories?q=Evidence+locker+Seed+in:readme" > evidencelockerevidence.txt
```

The above code does exactly what I need it to do (passes GHE token, calls api, stores it in a file) I just need help converting to python please.

EDIT: Solution was

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'token xxx',
}
url = 'https://github.ibm.com/api/v3/search/repositories?q=Evidence+locker+Seed+in:readme'

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response)
print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All `-H` tags need to be specified in the `headers` key, and the `url` is the first positional argument.

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer bearer_token',
}
url = 'https://github.com/api/v3/search/repositories?q=Evidence+locker+Seed+in:readme'

response = request.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response)
print(response.text)
```

That handles getting the data, now you have to worry about writing it to a file, which you can do with the `open` built-in function:

```
with open('path/to/evidencelockerevidence.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(response.text)
```

Comment: thank you very much for the help, I modified your code slightly to fit my need and it works, I've edited my comment with the solution